# Capturar el ultimo caracter de un nombre

Tags: java

Como capturar la ultima letra de un nombre `(Juan Pedro)` pero no sé que como lo podría hacer, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y les agradecería si me pudieran ayudar.

```
String nombre="Juan Pedro";
int cantidad=nombre.length();
String nomMay=nombre.toUpperCase();
String nomMin=nombre.toLowerCase();
char letraUno=nombre.charAt(0);
char letraDos=nombre.charAt(1);
System.out.println("Cantidad de letras: "+cantidad);
System.out.println("Mayusculas: "+nomMay);
System.out.println("Minusculas: "+nomMin);
System.out.println("Primera letra: "+letraUno);
System.out.println("Segunda letra: "+letraDos);
String a="";
String d=a+letraUno+letraDos;
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede realizar mediante el método [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-)  ,**`donde la posición será el length de la cadena -1`**.

```
char ultimo = nombre.charAt(nombre.length()-1);
System.out.println(ultimo);
```

O con el método [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) pasando el mismo parámetro que [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) , con la diferencia que [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) retorna un `String` y [charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-) un `carácter`.

```
String ultimo = nombre.substring(nombre.length() - 1);
System.out.println(ultimo);
```

Answer (score 0):

La ultima posición de una cadena se obtiene de la forma:

```
int posFinal = nombre.length()-1; //Restas uno para obtener el índice del ultimo caracter
char caracterFinal = nombre.charAt(posFinal);//obtienes el carácter de dicha posición
```

Answer (score 0):

> Un String en Java es una cadena de caracteres concatenados. Estos caracteres tienen un orden determinado

Ejemplo: El string "*casa*" es el conjunto de los caracteres:

```
C -> Primer caracter
A -> ...
S -> ...
A -> Último caracter
```

El orden que siguen comienza desde 0, hasta el último caracter, que es *length() - 1*, donde length() es el número total de caracteres que contiene ("casa" tiene 4)

Por tanto, el String "casa" queda así:

```
C -> 0
A -> 1
S -> 2
A -> 3
```

> Para recorrer un String almacenando cada caracter en una variable, lo más común es utilizar el bucle *for* y el método *charAt(int n)*, que devuelve el caracter que ocupa el lugar *n* :

```
String palabra = "casa";
char letra;
for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
    // Almacenamos cada caracter en la variable
    letra = palabra.charAt(i);
}
```

Por tanto, para obtener el último caracter:

```
char ultimo = palabra.charAt(palabra.length() - 1);
```

[Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)